# localStorage IE10. The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, internet-explorer-10

I'm currently experiencing an issue with localStorage on ie10. I have the following code snippet, which works on all browsers except ie10.

```
if (typeof (window.Storage) !== 'undefined' && localStorage.storageKey) {
    return localStorage.storageKey;
```

I've seen a few similar questions and it seems like a known bug, however all the answers accepted seem to be geared towards sorting out the browser settings... which unfortunately I'm unable to ask my users to do ;)

For the problem I need it for, sessionStorage is a viable solution, which doesn't cause any issues (which I can see), so I am able to use this.

```
if (typeof (window.Storage) !== 'undefined' && sessionStorage.storageKey) {
    return sessionStorage.storageKey;
```

However, I'm interested to know if anyone has experienced this and figured out a solution, without bringing in an external lib, to get localStorage working across the board?

Answer (score 1):

In IE10 localStorage won't work if u gonna use file URI scheme to access your application. Just deploy your application in any application-server like apache tomcat and then access your application via localhost.

Answer (score 0):

About localStorage briefly explaned  [click here](http://www.wintellect.com/blogs/jprosise/using-html5-web-storage-for-interprocess-communication)!
Useful for further working with localStorage